# Hive ETL - Partition data based on record pattern

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl

I have data stored in HDFS as Textfile with multiple lines. Every line has several records which 
can be organized as columns. For instance lines look like the ones below

```
Columns     A       B      C     D   E  F   G
       9/05/2014  14:17 312118  235 44 111 100
       ...
       9/05/2014  14:27 312118  255 48 111 103
```

I can create a schema and easily load all these lines in Hive, but what I really want is to
cluster them in small sets based on column "D" values. What I want is to partition my data in
a way that all records that have value D=235 and all records that follow this line, till i 
find a line where D value is equal to 255 to become a separate partition.

Just to clarify further what's the problem I need to address. Consider the case the
textfile has these records:

```
Columns     A       B      C     D   E  F   G
       9/05/2014  14:17 312118  235 44 111 100
       9/05/2014  14:18 312118  200 44 111 100
       9/05/2014  14:19 312118  200 44 111 100
       9/05/2014  14:20 312118  201 44 111 100
         ... (several more records)
       9/05/2014  14:27 312118  255 48 111 103
       9/05/2014  14:28 312118  235 44 111 100
         ... (several more records)
       9/05/2014  14:58 312118  255 44 111 100
```

I want to partition my data in such a way that each temporary table
will hold a set of data beginning with D value=235 and will have a last 
record with D value=255. In the above example ideally 2 tables should have been 
created temp1 and temp2 with values as below:

```
Temp1
      9/05/2014  14:17 312118  235 44 111 100
      9/05/2014  14:18 312118  200 44 111 100
      9/05/2014  14:19 312118  200 44 111 100
      9/05/2014  14:20 312118  201 44 111 100
        ... (several more records)
      9/05/2014  14:27 312118  255 48 111 103

Temp2
      9/05/2014  14:28 312118  235 44 111 100
        ... (several more records)
      9/05/2014  14:58 312118  255 44 111 100
```

Can I do that with HiveQL or is there another way to achieve this ETL process?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in a Hive table (which you said you can already do), less call it `t1`

create a new partitioned table for example :
`create table temp (a string,b string,c string,e string,f string,g string) partitioned by (d string)`

then simple insert the records from `t1` into `temp` in the following way :

`insert overwrite table temp partition (d)
select a,b,c,e,f,g,d from t1`

That's it.
For each new value of `d` a partition will be created in `temp` , all records with the same value of `d` will be put in that partition.

Answer (score 0):

U need to mention column D in your partition . All your data with distinct D values will be stored in a file .

The file in HDFS would be like /hdfspath>/D=235 , /hdfspath>/D=255

Hope this is what you are looking for